# How to join two collections on a common field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

In my database there are many issuers and many offerings. A user may create (and own) multiple issuers. I am trying to run a query
that will return all offerings associated with issuers that have been created by a given user. I want the returned result to include
the name of the issuer associated with the given offering (not just the ID).

Here is some abridged schema for context:

```
const OfferingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    issuerID: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    offeringName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
});
const Offering = mongoose.model('Offering', OfferingSchema, 'offerings');


const IssuerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user_id: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
});
const Issuer = mongoose.model("Issuer", IssuerSchema, "issuers");
```

From what I understand, I need to use `$lookup` to "join" the two collections. What I tried was this:

```
db.offerings.aggregate([{
    $lookup:{from: "issuers",       
            localField: "issuerID",  
            foreignField: "_id", 
            as: "issuerInfoAilias" }
}])
```

But I get back every offering, and each offering document has an `inssuerInfoAlias` field which is an empty array.

running the following query returns an offering with an `issuerID` of `5c953c18eb4a0a690892f001`

```
 db.offerings.findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5c9baa8b1fe76d79a108f3fb")})
```

Running the following query returns an issuer:

```
 db.issuers.findOne({"_id":ObjectId("5c953c18eb4a0a690892f001")})
```

So I know that at least one pair exists in the database.

I expect to get back all offerings with each offering including the name of the issuer that correlates to the id found in the `issuerID` field of the offering document. What change do I need to make in order to get that returned?

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see in your schema, i think you need to use `foreignField : "user_id"` instead of `foreignField : "_id"`.

Try this:

```
db.offerings.aggregate([{
    $lookup:{
        from: "issuers",       
        localField: "issuerID",  
        foreignField: "user_id", 
        as: "issuerInfoAilias" 
    }
}])
```

Comment: That won't work since the value that is being stored in the offering is the _id value that is generated when the issuer document is created. So an issuer has its own unique _id. (though I did try it just to see).

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?